# session_start problems when run process in parallel

Tags: php, session, iframe, asynchronous, locked

I need that both iframes forms work independent (async) but when i submit both forms at the same time the second iframe report "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\iframe2.php on line 2"  (when the iframe1 query is a long process) or the second iframe return data AFTER the first process is complete (when the iframe1 query is a short process).
Now, i need keep the session for validate user login.
i need your help, my friends! thanks

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="iframe1.php" width="300" height="400"></iframe>
<iframe src="iframe2.php" width="300" height="400"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe1.php (return query results)**

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['user'])
  $data="Valid user";
else
  header("location: login.php");

set_time_limit(120);
require_once("config.php"); //db conections
if($_POST)
{
  //query (long process)
  $data.= ""; // concatenated string with query results
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo session_id();?>
<form method="post">
ini:<input type="text" name="var1" value="" /><br />
fin:<input type="text" name="var2" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
Result:<br />
<?php
if(isset($data))
  echo session_id()."<hr>".$data;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe2.php (only return 123456)**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if($_SESSION['user'])
  $data="Valid user";
else
  header("location: login.php");

if($_POST)
{
  $data =  "123456";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo session_id();?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="inpt" />
<input type="submit" value="frame2" />
</form>

Result:<br />
<?php
if(isset($data))
  echo session_id()."<hr>".$data;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you not have a `set_time_limit(120);` in `iframe2.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Default PHP session have blocking file-access. That means as long as in your first script the session is still *active*, the second script's access to the session is blocked. PHP will wait until the session is accessible again.

The solution often is to keep the time-span short for the active period. Normally the sessions does not need to be active all the time.

You activate a session with `session_start()`.

You deactivate a session with `session_commit()`.

Locate the part of your script where you actually need an active session. Open it as late as possible (start) and close (commit) it as soon as possible.